# Django: Add a unique index on expressions in postgres

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

Consider the django model -

```
class Students(models.Model)
   id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
   scoreA = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=15)
   scoreB = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=15)
```

I'm looking to add this unique index.

```
create unique index unq_idx on students ((case  when scoreA is not NULL then scoreA else '' end), (case when scoreB is not NULL then scoreB else '' end));
```

How do I add it through the django ORM ?

I'm using Django 3.1 with postgres 12.1

The use-case is to have a unique constraint over the two fields which doesn't allow multiple NULL values ([Link](https://www.enterprisedb.com/postgres-tutorials/postgresql-unique-constraint-null-allowing-only-one-null))

Comment: In Django-3.2 you can create functional indexes, but not in 3.1.

Comment: But, even with Django-3.2, I don't see a way to create a functional unique index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working with Django 3.2 using [Index.expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/indexes/#expressions) and the UniqueIndex tweak from [django-postgres-extra](https://github.com/SectorLabs/django-postgres-extra/blob/master/psqlextra/indexes/unique_index.py)

```
class Students(models.Model)
   id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
   scoreA = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=15)
   scoreB = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=15)

   class Meta:
       indexes = [
           UniqueIndex(
               Case(When(scoreA__isnull=False, then=F('scoreA')), default=Value('')),
               Case(When(scoreB__isnull=False, then=F('scoreB')), default=Value('')),
               name='unique_idx'),
       ]
```

Answer (score 3):

As of [django-4.0](/questions/tagged/django-4.0), it will be possible to make [*functional* unique constraints <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint.expressions). In that case you can define such constraint with:

```
from django.db.models import UniqueConstraint, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

class Students(models.Model)
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    scoreA = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=15)
    scoreB = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(Coalesce('scoreA', Value('')), Coalesce('scoreB', Value('')), name='unique_score_combo')
        ]
```